# Bootstrap 4 modal - center + min-width

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

When adding a min-width on modal-content, I can't get it to center

```
@media screen and (min-width: 900px){
    .modal-content{
        min-width: 900px;
    }
}
```

I tried many things, here is a non exhaustive list

```
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
```

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Here is the modal-content div

```
<div role="document" class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
         <h5 id="doublonsModal" class="modal-title">title</h5>
         <p></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the parent container, modal-dialog, going to accommodate a content element of that size? It will have a default max width.

Comment: center how? vertically?

Comment: horizontally. I update my question :)

Comment: you will need Text-align center, justify-content center and align-items center. I would also like to point out that you don't have a modal-body.

Comment: I have, I just didn't put everything :) thanks!